# PHP: Only show first word of a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

This is my code for displaying a taxonomy (WordPress):

```
 <?php
    $locations = get_the_terms($post->ID , 'location');
        foreach ($locations as $location) {
            echo '<div class="term-location">';
            echo $location->name . ' ';
            echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

How can I modify the code to only display the first word of the taxonomy? I've tried it using explode but I can't get it to work (since my php knowledge is limited).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use explode so you were on the right path!

Explode returns an array of strings. So you first use explode, and then select the first item.

```
$locations = get_the_terms($post->ID , 'location');
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        echo '<div class="term-location">';
        echo explode(' ', $location->name)[0] . ' ';
        echo '</div>';
}
```

You can get more info on [explode here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), and an example on [getting the first word here](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/225401e3730e3332047852af8df34ede/).